# So if I don't see you till then

Tags: syntactic-analysis, synonyms

Often I hear the follow said (or similar variations):

> So if I don't see you till then, have a nice vacation.

Now I suppose that the intent is that if I don't see you until you leave, then I'll wish you **now** with *have a nice vacation*.

However, to me the sentence seems flawed if you take it at face value, in that it could sound like the wish *have a nice vacation* is only being given on the condition that  *I don't see you till then*.

So I'm wondering if

1. the given form of the sentence is in fact okay (and not flawed) and
2. Is there an alternative succinct way of saying the same thing?

Comment: A programmer’s wife sends him to the grocery store with the instructions, “get a loaf of bread, and if they have eggs, get a dozen.” He comes home with a dozen loaf of bread and tells her, “they had eggs.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence given in your example is correct for colloquial use, although as you've pointed out, it's somewhat idiomatic.

A more logically watertight example could be:

> I'll wish you a nice vacation now, in case I don't see you beforehand.